# Authentication error which testing trigger in Zapier

Tags: zapier

I want to set up the login trigger which triggers when user login in the system.

My Login API validate header with following data.

```
Header:
{
    "tenant-id": "{{tenant_id}}",
    "event-id": "{{event_id}}",
    "Api-Key": "{{api_key}}",
    "Device-id": "{{device_id}}"
}

Body:
{
    "email" : "{{email}}",
    "Password": "{{pwd}}"
}
```

While testing the trigger it always throwing 500 internal server error. But when I am testing my API with POSTMAN it is working great.

I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the implementation, the question and the details are quite vague. Are the `{{…}}` variables in the body and headers used to reference something in a Postman environment file?

Comment: of course,  {{value}} will be replaced with the different values. It was just dummy indication instead of real values.

Comment: Great that you answered that part of my comment, how about the first part and provided more details to the question?

Comment: I tried with GET method and it is working fine now. Just last question, Does Zapier trigger support POST method polling?